# channel is a required argument that is missing

Tags: discord.py

```py
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def clear(ctx, genre, channel):
        counter = 0
        ua = genre
        res = int(ua) + 1
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
            counter += 1
        a = await ctx.channel.purage(limit=res)
        if counter - res <= 0:
            await channel.send(f'{counter} messages has been deleted', delete_after=1.5)
        elif counter - res > 0:
            var = counter - res #how many messages left after chat.history counter - deleted messages counter
            result = counter - var - 1 #how many messages has been deleted
            await channel.send(f'{result} messages has been deleted', delete_after=1.5)
```

PS sorry for my bad English gramatic.
channel is not definded.
It is cleaner bot, who is cleaning chat, but when i write "channel" somewhere, code tells me that channel is not definded...Bot dont know what chat's history do i want to analize, but I want to analize that chat, in which I wrote a message. I dont know what to do.

Comment: Can you specify what error message you receive and on what line?

Comment: The error sounds like when you type the command in a channel, you forget a required argument. Can you tell us what you are sending to invoke the command?

Comment: `ctx.channel.purage` You spelt purge wrong, and I don't think your code would even cause that error you mentioned. Dpy requires you to type hint if you want a non-str type as a parameter, so channel is a str not a TextChannel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `Channel`, just remove it from your arguments.

You can use `ctx.channel` in your code.
Use in this case `ctx.channel.history`

PS.

You wrote `purage` wrong, because it's called `purge`.